# Regular expression to get only the first word from each line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file

```
@sp_id      int,    
@sp_name                varchar(120),
@sp_gender              varchar(10),
@sp_date_of_birth       varchar(10),
@sp_address             varchar(120),
@sp_is_active           int, 
@sp_role            int
```

Here, I want to get only the first word from each line. How can I do this? The spaces between the words may be **space** or **tab** etc.

Comment: yes, from each line I want the first word. so in the first line @sp_id

Comment: Any character from the left that is not a space or tab? ^[^\t ]+

Comment: Though the tag sais notepad++, there is nothing in the question connecting to it... So e.g. in perl you would do `/^(\S+)/`
 to get the first non space part of the line. Other systems use similar syntaxes.

Comment: Exactly. Depending on the RegEx dialect \S might not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find What:    `^(\S+).*$`

Replace by :  `\1`

You can simply use this to get the first word.Here we are capturing the first word in a group and replace the while line by the captured group.

Comment: what do use in "Find What" box?

Comment: if I put `^\S+` in `Find what:` then what to put in `Replace with:`

Comment: can you edit your answer, putting values for `Find what` and `Replace with`. Also please explain. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I suggest:

**Find what**: `^([^ \t]+).*`

**Replace with**: `$1`

*Explanation*: `^` matches the start of line, `([^ \t]+)` matches 1 or more (due to `+`) characters other than `space` and `tab` (due to `[^ \t]`), and then any number of characters up to the end of the line with `.*`.

See settings:

[image]

In case you might have leading whitespace, you might want to use

```
^\s*([^ \t]+).*
```

Comment: I forgot to say that `$1` is the back-reference to the text captured by the 1st capturing group (which is `([^ \t]+)`). I also assume you do not have empty first words :). Best regards.

Comment: Beginner question.  So basically ([^ \t]+) is capturing the first word on that line, is that correct?

Comment: @AndyUK Yes. I would in fact use `\S+` instead of `[^ \t]+` since `[^ \t]+` matches any chars but a regular space and tab, and thus can match line breaks.

Comment: Find: a `space` followed by `.*`  ↦ Replace with: `nothing ` gives me the same result as your Answer,  Mr Wiktor ....

Comment: @HajiRahmatullah Yes, unless there are leading spaces. In that case, you could use `^\s+` to replace them with an empty string first, then you could use ``" .*"`` and replace with an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar with this:

```
with open('handles.txt', 'r') as handles:
    handlelist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in handles]
    newlist = [str(re.findall("\w+", line)[0]) for line in handlelist]
```

This gets a list containing all the lines in the document,
then it changes each line to a string and uses regex to extract the first word (ignoring white spaces)

My file (handles.txt) contained info like this:

JoIyke - personal twitter link;

newMan - another twitter handle;

yourlink - yet another one.

The code will return this list:
[JoIyke, newMan, yourlink]

Comment: Question is about Notepad++, how this will work?

Answer (score 0):

Find the first word of each line with `/^\w+/gm`.